# Make reports 'terminated' during linking step

Tags: c++, subprocess, gnu-make

I'm developing an automated `c++` grading tool which builds and runs tests for student code. The system works fine, but occasionally the linking step fails, and `make` reports something along these lines:

```
clang++ -c main.cpp
clang++ -c foo.cpp
clang++ -c bar.cpp
clang++ main.o foo.o bar.o
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Terminated
```

For more context, `make` is being run via `Python`'s subprocess module (autograder is written in `Python`), and is being run from an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22.04 with at least 6GB of RAM. It seems to occur in ~5% or less of overall cases. Lastly, the programs being built are quite small (generally <5k lines of code overall, linking <10 files). The problem generally occurs in the linking step, but I've seen it during compilation of a given file as well.

The issue is resolved in every case by simply re-running the autograder.  Does anyone know why this might be happening? I've googled the issue but can't seem to find this specific problem.

Update:

After running with `make -d` as suggested, the relevant output is as follows:

```
...(successful builds above)...
Finished prerequisites of target file 'foo.o'.
  Must remake target 'foo.o'.
clang++ -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -O2 -c -o foo.o foo.cpp
Putting child 0x5597d3c65860 (foo.o) PID 67 on the chain.
Live child 0x5597d3c65860 (foo.o) PID 67 
Live child 0x5597d3c65860 (foo.o) PID 67 
Reaping losing child 0x5597d3c65860 PID 67 
make: *** [<builtin>: foo.o] Terminated
Removing child 0x5597d3c65860 PID 67 from chain
```

The above example was failure during compilation - here's one during linking:

```
Must remake target 'prog'.
clang++ -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -o prog main.o foo.o bar.o baz.o foobar.o
Putting child 0x560a298357c0 (prog) PID 64 on the chain.
Live child 0x560a298357c0 (prog) PID 64 
make: *** Deleting file 'prog'
Live child 0x560a298357c0 (prog) PID 64 
Reaping losing child 0x560a298357c0 PID 64 
make: *** [Makefile:14: prog] Terminated
Removing child 0x560a298357c0 PID 64 from chain.
```

Comment: Run `make` with the `-d`  (debug) or `--trace` (to print tracing information) options. Might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: reran with `make -d` - relevant output added to answer.

Comment: You should run `dmesg` or the system log files (journalctl or whatever facility you use for system logging) when this happens, and look for suspicious messages.  A "Terminated" line like this means that some other process sent a SIGTERM signal to make.  It's not something that make did on its own.  So, some other facility on the OS you're using is killing make.  It's highly unlikely you'll see anything in the `-d` output, since this is not related to make itself, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; as suggested by @MadScientist, the issue was `make` being killed by the os due to running out of memory. Details below.

One of the first steps of our autograder is to pull the most recent version of the grading files from the course repo. Turns out that this issue happens for us when the `git pull` requires a large update
requiring a few GB of RAM. Looks like (for reasons unknown to me) the RAM usage persisted after the pull, such that during the usual `make` step the memory limits were overrun, and there it was. Our working solution is to rebuild the docker container with a more recent version of the repo when we make certain changes (needs to be done ~1/month or so). Of course ideally we wouldn't have git be tracking large file databases which change infrequently (changes to which caused the problem), but that's unlikely to change for now. Thanks for the tips, all.